# Parametric equations for a point traversing the circumference of a laterally accelerating circle (not rolling) with a max speed for the point.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, circles, parametric, word-problem

Variables:
e -> point on a circle
r -> radius of said circle (constant)
x(t), y(t) -> parametric equations describing the position of point e
v -> velocity of the center of the circle
c -> constant speed of point e (also max speed of the circle; de/dt = c, 0 <= |v| <= c)

I'm looking to describe the motion of a point e that moves along the circumference of a circle, where the circle can be translated along the x-axis at any speed between 0 and c.
Point e has a constant speed of c, which means the following:

**@ v = 0**
`x(t) = r*cos(t), y(t) = r*sin(t)`
This is because when the circle is not moving, the point e just moves around the circumference.

**@ v = c**
`x(t) = c*t, y(t) = y(0)`
This is because when the circle is moving at the same speed of e (c), then e must have the same velocity vector as the center of the circle for it to remain on the circumference and maintain speed c.

I thought of something like this:

```
x(t) = r*cos(t)*(1 - v/c) + v*t
y(t) = r*sin(t)*(1 - v/c)
```

Since this reduces to the correct equations at v=0 and v=c, plus the angular speed is proportional to the velocity of the circle.
But this doesn't satisfy the constant velocity requirement where:
`(dx/dt)^2 + (dy/dt)^2 = c^2`
At least not as far as I can see.

Comment: Do you know the equation for a circle with midpoint (x1,y1) then just set x1=v*t if you start at (0,0) if you start at (x0,y0)  use x1=x0+v*t

Answer (score 0):

You write

> Point e has a constant speed of c, which means the following:

> **@ v = 0**
> `x(t) = r*cos(t), y(t) = r*sin(t)`
> This is because when the circle is not moving, the point e just moves around the circumference.

But if $x$ and $y$ are the coordinates of your point $e$, then $e$ in this case is moving with speed $r$, **not** speed $c$. I think you need to adjust this case to be
$$
x(t) = r  \cos(t\frac{c}{r})\\
y(t) = r  \sin(t\frac{c}{r})
$$
so that
$$
x'(t) = -r(\frac{c}{r})  \sin(t\frac{c}{r}) = -c \sin(t\frac{c}{r})\\
y'(t) = r (\frac{c}{r}) \cos(t\frac{c}{r}) = c \cos(t\frac{c}{r})
$$
from which it's evident that $x'(t)^2 + y'(t)^2 = c^2$ as desired.

In the case where the point is translating as well as rotating, we don't necessarily know what to put into the argument of the sine and cosine instead of $t\frac{c}{r}$, so let's just say 'it's some function $s(t)$' for now. Then we get, for a translational motion at speed $q$, with $0 \le q \le c$ the equations

\begin{align}
x(t) &= qt + r \cos(s(t))
y(t) &= r\sin(s(t))
\end{align}
and taking derivatives, we get
\begin{align}
x'(t) &= q - r \cos(s(t)) s'(t)
y'(t) &= r\cos(s(t))
\end{align}
Setting $x'(t)^2 + y'(t)^2 = c^2$ yields a constraint on the function $s$:
$$
\left[q^2 -2rq \cos(s(t)) s'(t) + r^2 \cos^2(s(t)) (s'(t))^2\right] +
\left[ r^2 \sin^2(s(t)) (s'(t))^2\right]  = c^2.
$$
Gathering the squared sine and cosine terms, and moving constants to the right hand side,we have
$$
-2rq \cos(s(t)) s'(t) +  r^2s'(t)^2 = c^2 - q^2
$$
Divide through by $r^2$ to get
$$
s'(t)^2 -2\frac{q}{r} \cos(s(t)) s'(t)  = \frac{c^2 - q^2}{r^2}
$$
Now completing the square (i.e., rewriting $x^2 + 2bx$ as $x^2 + 2bx + b^2 - b^2 = (x+b)^2 - b^2$) we get
\begin{align}
s'(t)^2 &-2\frac{q}{r} \cos(s(t)) s'(t) + \left[\frac{q}{r} \cos(s(t))\right]^2 - \left[\frac{q}{r} \cos(s(t))\right]^2= \frac{c^2 - q^2}{r^2} \\
(s'(t)- &\left[\frac{q}{r} \cos(s(t))\right])^2 = \frac{c^2 - q^2}{r^2} + \left[\frac{q}{r} \cos(s(t))\right]^2\\
(s'(t)- &\left[\frac{q}{r} \cos(s(t))\right]) = \sqrt{\frac{c^2 - q^2}{r^2} + \left[\frac{q}{r} \cos(s(t))\right]^2}\\
s'(t)& = \sqrt{\frac{c^2 - q^2}{r^2} + \left[\frac{q}{r} \cos(s(t))\right]^2} + \left[\frac{q}{r} \cos(s(t))\right]\\
\end{align}
which is a differential equation for $s$, but not one that admits a simple solution by any means. I mean, the solution can be expressed as an integral:
\begin{align}
s(t)& = K + \int_0^t \sqrt{\frac{c^2 - q^2}{r^2} + \left[\frac{q}{r} \cos(s(u))\right]^2} + \left[\frac{q}{r} \cos(s(u))\right] ~du
\end{align}
but that integral isn't likely to be easy to write out in elementary terms.

Comment: Ah thank you  I cannot believe I missed the fact that x'^2 + y'^2 = r^2....silly mistake ugh. There's no rotational motion of the circle so I'll hopefully be able to reduce some complexity when I get back to a laptop/pen and paper. Thanks!